# X11 on CentOS VM with OS X Lion client

Tags: osx-lion, xorg, centos-6, oracle-10g, vagrant

I am using `OS X Lion`. I have a Vagrant box running `CentOS 6.0 minimal` on my mac. I am trying to install `Oracle 10g` on my CentOS 6. I keep getting an error

```
Can't connect to X11 window server
```

I have tried setting the `DISPLAY` variable to all the possible values; localhost, CentOS IP addr, Lion IP addr..
I just keep getting this error.

`xclock` doesn't work on CentOS (even as `root`). But `xclock` works fine on Lion.

How can I fix this error? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You installed CentOS minimal, so you don't have an X server running locally in the VM.  If you want to try to install one, http://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=36887&forum=55 has some information about getting an X server set up (it's unfortunately easiest to simply set up one of the desktop environments).

You cannot use the X server in Lion for this directly from inside the VM, unless you enable insecure network connections.  Better would be to `ssh -Y` into the VM from Lion; you can then run X11 programs from within that session with X11 forwarding to Lion's X server.

Comment: I have run `yum groupinstall "X Window System"`

Comment: Okay, if that didn't configure and launch a display manager, you will then need to run `startx` to actually launch it; then you can run the installer from within a terminal window.  (Linux is not like OS X; there is no `launchd` configured to autostart X11.)

Comment: When I run `startx`, the terminal halts at `expected keysym, got XF86TouchpadOff: line 121 of inet`. And I have to run the Oracle installer from a different session. On running the installer I get `Preparing to launch Oracle Universal Installer from /tmp/OraInstall2012-04-22_05-30-43AM. Please wait ...`..and it breaks and comes back to my prompt

Comment: That sounds like it has started X11 in a different virtual console but not switched you over to it for some reason (the "hang" is because the server is running in the foreground).  Try switching consoles with `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F`n (that is, function keys `F1`, `F2`, etc.; X11 often starts on `F7`) until you find the one with the X11 session; the Oracle installer should have a window open there.

Comment: Does this work with Mac? I am on CentOS in terminal (no graphics). `Alt`+`Fn` opens OS X applications. `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`Fn` does not do anything.

Comment: I am not specifically familiar with the virtualization product you're using (Vagrant) but it sounds like it may not provide a graphics mode or access to Linux virtual consoles.  If that's the case, the `ssh -Y` I mentioned earlier is the only way you'll be able to do this.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. My windows were accessible from VirtualBox. I had to make a few changes in the Vagrant configuration and then reboot to be able to see it.